# UICollectionView: AutoSizing cells, increase the height of the button

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uibutton, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

Currently, I have the code as follows:

```
class MyClass: UICollectionViewCell {
  override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let autoLayoutAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width, height: 0)
    let autoLayoutSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
    let autoLayoutFrame = CGRect(origin: autoLayoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: autoLayoutSize)
    autoLayoutAttributes.frame = autoLayoutFrame
    return autoLayoutAttributes
  }

  lazy var button = MyCustomButtonWithAppliedStyles()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.addSubview(button)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.leading.trailing.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
      make.height.equalTo(contentView.snp.height).dividedBy(2)
      make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

which results in the following:

[image: Current result]

I would like to specify the height of the button to be a bit bigger.
Here is the result I'd like to achieve:
[image: Goal]

I can get it by adding a single constraint:

```
make.height.equalTo(44)
```

The problem is that I'm getting an AutoLayout error messages:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6040002948c0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fbc246207d0.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000bdca0@ListItemButtonCell.swift#31 SelfCare.MyCustomButtonWithAppliedStyles:0x7fbc24621f10.height == 44.0>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000bdbe0@ListItemButtonCell.swift#29 SelfCare.MyCustomButtonWithAppliedStyles:0x7fbc24621f10.height == UIView:0x7fbc246207d0.height * 0.5>"
)
```

How can I fix this error? What could be the direction to debug this issue, or rewrite the layout code, if I already know the desired height of the cell and the button, but **would like to use AutoSizing** on the rest of the UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: The issue is with conflicting constraints: `make.height.equalTo(contentView.snp.height).dividedBy(2)` and `make.height.equalTo(44)`. You can set the constraints to leading/trailing and top/bottom edges so that the button grows with the cell size.

Comment: @VidyaMurthy that works, but I need a button to be bigger than its `intrinsicContentSize`, please take a look at my answer below. I fixed it by modifying the `intrinsicContentSize`, still, I'm unable to set a specific height to the button or cell.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the desired result by setting the `contentEdgeInsets` property.

Here is the configuration code I've ended working with:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.leading.trailing.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
  make.height.equalTo(contentView.snp.height).dividedBy(2)
  make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Still, neither the cell, nor the button height are fixed and could be altered i.e. when user changes their font preferences (DynamicType), so the question is still open.